# Changing a specific value from another class in java

Tags: java

Hi I'm trying to make a basic program that will increment a given number until it finds the next prime number, but I'm having problem making it work

```
 PrimeNumber(long eNumb)
 {
   number= eNumb;
 }

 public static void incrementNumber()
 {
   this.number = number + 1;
 }


 boolean foundNext = false;
 PrimeNumber findNext = new PrimeNumber(next);
   while (!foundNext) 
   {
       if (PrimeNumber.isPrime())
       {
        foundNext = true;
       }
       else
       {
        FindNext.incrementNumber();
       }
   }
```

I have the isPrime() method working, but I seem to be entering an infinite loop.
Sorry if the question is unclear
EDIT : I entered the wrong code, still wants answer though.

Comment: Is `isPrime` checking `this.number`?

Comment: that code won't even compile. you have a while block outside of any method. Please post the correct code.

Comment: what is the code for the method `isPrime()` ?

Comment: Are you sure `PrimeNumber.incrementNumber()` works? `incrementNumber` is not `static` as I see.

Answer (score 0):

```
foundNext = true is always true, I think you have to make it false 
any were in your program.
```

Suppose,

```
while (!foundNext) {
//  foundNext = false;  make it false on basis of any condtion
}
```

Comment: the condition is negated, assigning `true` to `foundNext` will break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Problem liss here:

```
while (!foundNext) // it schould check if foundNext is prime number
```

Code can be simplified like so:

```
PrimeNumber(long eNumb)
 {
   this.number= eNumb;
 }

 public void incrementNumber()
 {
   this.number++;
 }

... // some code here. I assume that code below is inside some method.

 PrimeNumber findNext = new PrimeNumber(next);
   while (!findNext.isPrime()) // in tis solution I assume that number is not static field
   {
        findNext.incrementNumber();
   }
```